# A problem connecting to a MySQL DB using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc, connection

Here's how I'm trying to connect:

```
try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new DbConnectionException();
   }
   try {
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new DbConnectionException();
   }
```

I'm 100% sure that the url, username, password strings are correct. I've already connected successfully using an external tool (MySQL query browser). 
This is the error I receive:

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure due to
>   underlying exception:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.net.SocketException MESSAGE:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused
>
> ...

Comment: Is MySQL server running? Is the port unblocked from the firewall?

Comment: the firewall blocked your MySQL port? Try unblocking it.

Comment: @The Elite: Sorry. I meant Yes. Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly a `url` issue. If your code is pointing to MySQL `localhost`, try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` on your url.

E.g.:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MY_DB
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MY_DB
```

And see if this works.

Comment: Indeed a url issue. Turns out I had another piece of code which was trying to connect to another DB and it caused the problem. Sorry for being 100% sure on something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

did you run the mysql browser from the same machine where the code is running?  What I am getting at is the permissions in mysql can be host-specific, and depending on how you set them up you might not be able to connect from the machine where the code is running.

Also, you  might want to double check the url, name, pword again, perhaps with log statements or a debugger to make sure there are no typos, trailing whitespaces, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Double check the format of your url.  It should start with "jdbc:mysql:".  Make sure you are using a current version for the driver as well.

Comment: Indeed a url issue. Turns out I had another piece of code which was trying to connect to another DB and it caused the problem. Sorry for being 100% sure on something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you can connect to the database from the mysql admin tool, that will drive out whether your mysql is running and that the port is open.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was using a connection from emulator to localhost.

If you use emulator to localhost don't use `localhost` value in connection String but use `10.0.2.2` instead:

```
jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/MY_DB
```

Hope this helps.